# GitLab: Web Module not showing properly

Tags: browser, gitlab

Yesterday I installed GitLab on my local Server. Then I accessed it through one of the computers on the LAN. 
Now If I open GitLab from this computer GitLab shows like this:
[image]

Tried changing firefox security settings but to no avail.
Now trying to open on Chrome, and Nginx. 
Please help!